# Executar código apenas se o usuario não estiver na aba

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer para rodar um script (neste caso são aquelas notificações de desktop) apenas se o usuario **não estiver com a aba aberta**, ou seja, quero enviar uma notificação de desktop para ele apenas se ele não estiver com o site aberto (estou fazendo isso com ajax) mas não sei como fazer isso no javascript! Tentei utilizar:

```
$(window).focus(function(){
  //your code
});
```

mas não funcionou...

Obrigado!

Código completo:

```
$(window).focusout(function() {

            Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
                        // Whatever the user answers, we make sure we store the information
                        if (!('permission' in Notification)) {
                            Notification.permission = permission;
                        }

                        // If the user is okay, let's create a notification
                        if (permission === "granted") {
                            var options = {
                                body: "TEXTO_DA_NOTIFICACAO",
                                icon: "IMAGEM",
                                dir : "ltr"
                            };
                            var notification = new Notification("TITULO",options);
                        }
                });

            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade o `$.focus` tem por finalidade detectar quando o usuário está e não quando ele saiu, você deve utilizar os recursos `$.focusout` ou `$.blur`:

```
$(window)
.focusout(function() {

})
.blur(function() {

});
```

Comment: Utilizei o .focusout mas não funcionou, agora ele nao envia a notificação, vou editar a pergunta e colocar o codigo completo!

Comment: É que na verdade nao quero saber quando ele saiu, eu apenas preciso checar se a aba está aberta ou não

Comment: tentou com o blur?

Comment: Tentei e tambem nao foi, mas consegui resolver!

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

```
var mouseFora = !$("html").is(":hover");

if(mouseFora) {

// CODIGO

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi e usando o que já foi sugerido pelas outras respostas: guarde o *status* da página num sinalizador, atualizando-o conforme o usuário focaliza ou oculta a aba.

```
const pagina = { sendoVista: true };
$(window).focus(function() {
    pagina.sendoVista = true;
}).blur(function() {
    pagina.sendoVista = false;
});
```

No código AJAX (ou de outro tipo) que exibe notificações, basta perguntar ao sinalizador e disparar os alertas somente quando o usuário estiver em outra aba.

É claro que tudo aqui embaixo está sujeito a mudanças.